# error when use type variant in Rust struct

Tags: rust, struct, rust-analyzer

I want to use type in struct but I get error

```
pub struct Hello {
    pub type: String,
}
```

and I got this error

```
Syntax Error: expected COLON rust-analyzersyntax-error
Syntax Error: expected type rust-analyzersyntax-error
Field `String` should have snake_case name, e.g. `string` rust-analyzernon_snake_case
```

I want to use type and I don't now how to use field with name type in struct ??

Comment: `type` is a keyword.